# Django - model structure

Tags: python, django, database, model, structure

I'm new to Django and I'm having a situation here re my model structure:

I've got a model `Item` representing a lot of items for sale.

Some of the items have the `tag`. Some don't.

Whichever has the `tag` would have the same `percentage` of discount: five options for the user to choose (5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, 25%);

When the administrator/user increases the discount say from 5% to 15%, ALL of the items with the tag would have the same 15% discount.

I'm not sure if I should set a boolean `tag` field and then another field for `percentage` or even another model hosting the discount `percentage` choices, or should I just set an IntegerField of tag choices for `percentage`? But how to keep all the items with the same tag sync? Is there a way which consumes the least resources?

Comment: How about a new model called `Tag` (with value for % off), with a many-to-one relationship between `Item-Tag`? Set the initialization of `Tag` inside `Item` as default `None`, and then given specific `Item`s specific `Tag`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a nullable field that refers to a `Tag` model, and let the `Tag` modle contain the percentage. For example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

class Tag(models.Model):
    percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)

class Item(models.Model):
    # …
    discount_tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    @property
    def discount(self):
        if self.discount_tag is not None:
            return self.discount_tag.percentage
        return Decimal()
```

Here we can thus for example add a `@property` that checks if the `Item` has a related tag, if so, it returns the `percentage` of that `discount_tag`. Otherwise, it returns `Decimal('0')`.